# How to change the default remote where to push tags?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-config, git-tag, git-fork

In my repo, the *branches* usually are specified explicitly what *remote* should `push` to (to `origin` or to `fork`).

Unfortunately lightweight *tags* (that I am using just for development, at the moment) don't have the same option.

I've wrongly done `git push --tags` and all of were copied to the wrong *remote*. Lot of dirt; so I had to clean up all of them manually.

**How to specify what *remote* the tags should be pushed by default?**

NOTE: I usually push *lightweight tags* on `fork`, as bookmarks for later reuse (to mark commits that I don't want into a branch).

Comment: Tags are pushed by default to the same destination as your current branch. If you want them to go somewhere else you'll need to specify an explicit remote.

Comment: Use a git alias like `git config alias.push-tags push myfork --tags`. Now train yourself to always do `git push-tags`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default remote for tags, only for branches. When you push a tag without specifying the remote, it will go to the default for the branch you are on, aka the *remote-tracking branch*.

Use `git branch -vv` to see the tracking branches for each local branch.

Use `git branch -u <desired upstream remote> [<branchname>]` to change them. The last arg is optional and defaults to the same name as the local branch.